# Does `apt-get install` install dependencies of dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Does `apt-get install` install dependencies of dependencies?

For example, considering package clamsmtp, among other dependencies it needs clamav-daemon, and clamav-daemon, among other dependencies, needs clamav-base and clamav-freshclam, etc.

So, if I use:

```
sudo apt-get install clamsmtp
```

Will it automatically install the needed dependencies and those dependencies' dependencies, and so on, until all dependencies are met?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it installs everything needed, and by default also installs everything recommended.

Comment: Great, thanks. It simplifies installation to be able to just specify a specialized application and let it find what it needs/uses.